# Split camelcase value with TCL

Tags: tcl

I have this TCL expression:

```
[string toupper [join [lrange [file split [value [topnode].file]] 1 1]]]
```

This retrieves `companyName` value from `c:/companyName...` and I need to split that value before the first capital letter into `Company Name`. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's rather more in one word than I would consider a good idea. It makes the whole thing quite opaque! Let's split it up.

Firstly, I would expect the base company name to be better retrieved with `lindex` from the split filename.

```
set companyName [lindex [file split [value [topnode].file]] 1]
```

Now, we need to process that to get the human-readable version out of it. Alas, that's going be a bit difficult without knowing what's been done to it, but if we use as our example `fooBarBoo_grill` then we can see what we can do. First, we get the pieces with some regular expressions (this part might need tweaking if there are non-ASCII characters involved, or if certain critical characters need special treatment):

```
# set companyName "fooBarBoo_grill"
set pieces [regexp -all -inline {[a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]*} $companyName]
# pieces = foo Bar Boo grill
```

Next, we need to capitalise. I'll assume you're using Tcl 8.6 and so have `lmap` as it is perfect for this task. The `string totitle` command has been around for a very long time.

```
set pieces [lmap word $pieces {string totitle $word}]
# pieces = Foo Bar Boo Grill
```

That list might need a bit more tweaking, or it might be OK as it is. An example of tweaking that might be necessary is if you've got an Irish name like `O'Hanrahan`, or if you need to insert a comma before and period after `Inc`.

Finally, we properly ought to `set companyName [join $pieces]` to get back a true string, but that doesn't have a noticeable effect with a list of words made purely out of letters. Also, more complex joins with regular expressions might be needed if you've done insertion of prefixing punctuation (the `, Inc.` case).

---

If I was doing this for real, I'd try to have the proper company name expressed directly elsewhere rather than relying on the filename. Much simpler to get right!

Comment: Thank you both Donal and Peter!
I ended up using the expression like this in one row and worked like a charm:

`[string toupper [regexp -all -inline {[a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]*} [lindex [file split [value [topnode].file]] 1]]]`

I'm still using `toupper` because I need to end result to be all capitals.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, try using

```
lindex [file split [value [topnode].file]] 1
```

The `lrange` command will return a list, which might cause problems with some directory names. The `join` command should be pointless if you don't use `lrange`, and `string toupper` removes the information you need to do the operation you want to do.

To split before uppercase letters, you can use repetitive matches of either `(?:[a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]+)` (ASCII / English alphabet letters only) or `(?:[[:lower:]]+|[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+)` (any Unicode letters).

```
% regexp -all -inline {(?:[a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]+)} camelCaseWord
camel Case Word
```

Use `string totitle` to change the first letter of the first word to upper case.

Documentation:
[file](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm),
[lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm),
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)